# Firefox 2017 - hilight the active tab

Tags: css, firefox, tabs

I am currently (Nov,2017) using Firefox 56.0.2 Both in Windows-10 and Ubuntu.
I'd like to **HIGHLIGHT** the  **active tab**  in Firefox - it tends to get lost with many tabs open. And my old eyes ain't what they used to be.

There is a lot of OLD info from several years ago (2006-2011), on how to add/modify Firefox to do this, but basically advise to modify the "chrome.css" or a variation thereof in Firefox "profiles".

I cannot seem to locate or navigate to any of this stuff- Firefox must have been modified extensively in the latest few versions. A CSS file cannot be found anywhere.

I am not interested in any of the eye-candy Firefox add-ons- tried 'em and they are not what I want. All I want is for the **ACTIVE TAB to be HIGHLIGHTED-** background, colour and font.

Once I can have this, then I'll worry about eye-candy backgrounds, etc. And perhaps use my own CSS params.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the userChrome.css file in your profile directory, inside the chrome directory (profile dir > chrome > userchrome.css) if it doesn't exist.
Search online how to find your userchrome.css location for firefox inside the chrome dir - it's not hard.

For firefox 72, (on windows) use this inside userChrome.css:
( inside userChrome.css you can link other .css files that are in the same folder using @import, e.g.: `@import url("userChrome_tabs_settings.css");` )

You can use this code inside userChrome.css to customize your tabs - the backgr. colors, borders, text color (add or remove borders , change border colros), to your liking:

If you don't like the colors I've chosen, you can use an online html color picker to choose your colors, e.g.: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");


/*tab bar region that has no tabs plus the arrows that scroll the tabs to the left and right*/
#tabbrowser-tabs {
  width: 100vw !important;
  background-color: var(--toolbar-bgcolor) !important;

  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(250, 252, 255), rgb(235, 243, 251)) !important;*/
  background: rgb(249, 249, 250) !important;
  color:rgb(82, 82, 82) !important;
  
  
  /* the border that separates the tabs and the tab arrows from the new tab button and bookmarks */
  border: solid 0.1em;
  border-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, .4) !important;
  
  
}


/* active tab */
#tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab[selected] .tab-content { 
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(250, 252, 255), rgb(235, 243, 251) ) !important;*/
  /*background: rgb(250, 252, 255) !important;*/

 
  /* border-color not working without specifying the size first*/
  border: solid 0.3em;
  /*border-color: red yellow green transparent !important;*/ /* example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color */
  /*border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent!important;*/
  border-color: rgb(10, 132, 255) transparent transparent transparent!important;

  
  background: rgb(250, 252, 255) !important;

  /* text color - only works when using background-color, does not work with background */
  color: black !important;
}


/* inactive tabs */
#TabsToolbar .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected]) {
  /*border-color: rgba(210,0,0,.2) !important;*/
  /*background:rgb(249, 249, 250) !important;*/
  /* background-color: rgba(155,152,150,.99) !important;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(166, 166, 166), rgb(235, 243, 251) ) !important;*/
  

  /*border-color: rgba(82, 82, 82,.2) !important;*?
  /*background: rgb(249, 249, 250) !important;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(208, 220, 234), rgb(184, 196, 208) ) !important; */
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(230, 230, 230), rgb(219, 219, 219) ) !important; */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(242, 242, 244), rgb(230, 230, 233) ) !important;

  /* text color - works with background and background-color*/
  color: rgb(0,0,0) !important;
  
    
  /* cannot change the border size of the inactive tabs, only the top border of the inactive tabs can be colored */

  /* the border from #tabbrowser-tabs section includes the tab arrows, the border for the tabs does not - so you can use 2 borders at the same time for the tabs */
  border-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, .4) !important;


}





/* tabs when the mouse pointer is hovering on them */
#TabsToolbar .tabbrowser-tab:hover:not([selected]) {
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;


  /*background: #662b99 !important;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5) !important;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(#9198e5, #ba8fe5) !important;*/
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9198e5, #ba8fe5) !important;

  
  /*background-color: rgb(50,50,50) !important;*/

  /* text color */
  /*color: rgb(0,0,0) !important;*/
  color: white !important;

}






/* padding (transparent space filled with OS theme color) between the bookmarks bar and the tab bar if the tab bar is on the botton, below the bookmarks bar */
/*
*|*:root:not([chromehidden*="toolbar"]) #navigator-toolbox {
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--tab-min-height) + 1px) !important;
}

*/



/* TABS: height */
/*
*|*:root {
  --tab-toolbar-navbar-overlap: 0px !important;
  --tab-min-height: 40px !important; *//*adjust to set height or omit to use density*/ /*
}
*/





/* New tab button */
#TabsToolbar .tabs-newtab-button,
#TabsToolbar #new-tab-button > .toolbarbutton-icon {

/* you can change the new tab button shape using a .svg file*/
  list-style-image: url("chrome://browser/skin/new-tab.svg") !important;
  
  fill: rgb(82, 82, 82) !important;*/
  /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;*/
  background: rgb(208, 226, 243) !important;
  
}


#TabsToolbar #new-tab-button:hover > .toolbarbutton-icon {
  list-style-image: url("chrome://browser/skin/new-tab.svg") !important;
  fill: #999999 !important;
  
  /*background: linear-gradient(rgb(208, 226, 243), #dbe9f5) !important;*/
  background: #e1e1e1 !important;
}
```

Here's how it looks:
[custom tabs colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myQv2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use a simple method to highlight active tab, but till now only found [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) plugin to work well on my FireFox 52.

To change active tab color, go to CTR preferences --> Tabs --> Color & Text --> Selected Tab:

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this add-on i is not compatable with FF Quantum.     And I am NOT reverting to ESR!